# Unified data format for blood pressure (and other medical data) statistics?

Tags: format, medical, pressure, unified-log

Do you know about unified formats for medical data, specially blood pressure? For example, I want to record data using my smartphone and export it to json or xml and send to a doctor, doctor imports it in his software. Is it real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Look here for the HL7 standard for clinical observations;

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/observation.html